# fill element array buffer without modifying VAO (4.1)

Tags: opengl

I would like to fill a VBO with element indices, and then later bind it to the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER slot on a VAO.

The obvious (but wrong) code is:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementArrayBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...);
```

but that changes the current VAO, or could cause an error if there is no VAO bound. I don't want to do that, I just want to fill the buffer, and then use it at some later point

If this would be OpenGL 4.5 (which osx doesn't support), the solution would be to just use `glNamedBufferData`, and not bind it until later.

Is there a reasonable way around this?

Can i use the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` slot to fill the buffer, and then bind it to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` later, or would that be against the spec?

Comment: Interesting question.  Can I ask what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffer objects are in no way directly associated with particular targets. When you bind a buffer for the purpose of modifying it, you can bind it to [*any* valid buffer target](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#General_use). You could bind it to `GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER` just to call `glBufferSubData` on it. You could also use `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, but for such circumstances, it's best to use an innocuous binding point.